# Cómo mostrar imágenes en base64 en Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mongodb

Quiero mostrar en Angular imágenes de ubicaciones que me devuelve mi base de datos en base64 pero no sé si estoy asignándole el tipo de dato correcto en Typescript

Mi backend me devuelve ubicaciones con el siguiente formato:

```
[{"name":"Parque de los Cineastas",
"neighbourhood":"Actur-Rey Fernando",
"rating":0,
"coords":[-0.8839716,41.6783155],
"leisure":"park",
"img":{"contentType":"image/jpeg","data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255......]}}
```

y tengo un modelo en Typescript con los siguientes parámetros:

```
export class Ubicacion{
    name: String;
    neighbourhood: boolean;
    rating: number;
    coords: string[];
    leisure: string;
    img: any;
}
```

(No sé si el tipo de dato any es adecuado para el parámetro `img`)

Lo que necesito es poder mostrar esa imagen en el HTML, lo he intentado este código:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let ubicacion of ubicaciones">
    <div class="card">
       <div class="row">
          <img class="img" [src]="getImgContent(ubicacion)" alt="Imagen" style="width:100%">
          <h4><b>{{ubicacion.name}}</b></h4> 
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y esta es la función en el componente ts:

```
public ubicaciones: Ubicacion[];

constructor(private service:PrincipalService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

getImgContent(ubi: Ubicacion):SafeUrl {
    console.log(ubi.img);
    var imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + 
    (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(ubi.img) as any).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
    return imgSrc;
  }
```

Obtengo el warning `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value` porque en el `imgSrc` aparece un objeto indefinido